Retrieving Video Insights with Specified Time Range within Lifetime Period
I'm working with the Facebook Graph API to retrieve video insights, and I've encountered a situation where specifying the since and until parameters doesn't seem to affect the results when the period is set to "lifetime."
Here's an example of the API request I'm using:
/[VIDEO_ID]/video_insights?metric=total_video_views&since=2023-01-01&until=2023-03-01&period=lifetime
Even when I include the since and until parameters to specify a time range within the lifetime period, I'm getting the same result as when I don't include these parameters.
Additionally, I need to retrieve data for total_video_view_time_by_country_id and total_video_view_time_by_age_bucket_and_gender within the given period.
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? Is there a specific reason why specifying the time range within the lifetime period wouldn't affect the results? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help! 
